# Flex 3: <mx:list> hover background color

Tags: apache-flex, list

How do I change the background color of the item I'm currently hovering over in a list?  The default is that light blue, but I would like to be able to change it to whatever I want.  I've gone through the list of available options, but I didn't see anything that stuck out at me.

I'm sure this is ridiculously simple, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: fairly sure it's just a style property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
useRollOver="false"
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the [rollOverColor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#style%3arollOverColor) style?  The docs say this style represents:

> The color of the background of a
>   renderer when the user rolls over it.

Comment: I tried setting up a style and declaring the rollOverColor, but it didn't work... it stayed blue :(

Comment: @Brds Do you have the roll over color set to blue in the CSS? The solution fro www.Flextras.com should work i think.